# SiteEdit Authentication Issue

Tags: tridion, siteedit

I am currently installing SiteEdit 2009 SP3 and running into an issue with authentication.

My setup is of the following:

1. Installed SiteEdit on the same server as the Tridion CME and entered the IP of the Tridion CME and staging URL; i.e. "www.mysite.com" during installation
2. Created a host in IIS; i.e. "se_www.mysite.com" and added the host to the server host file
3. Configured sitedit for LDAP

   - added LdapAuthenticationHttpModule to httpModules section of the webconfig
   - added the tridion.contentmanager.config to the tridion config section of the webconfig
   - added WebUI location element to the webconfig
4. Configured authentication for the SiteEdit website in IIS and only enabled anonymous access and basic access

Now when I try to visit "se_www.mysite.com", it properly prompts me for login credentials, but after entering them, it prompts me for them again. I went through the installation steps again to make sure nothing was missed, but the issue still remains. Has anyone encountered such issue or know what is potentially causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To enable SiteEdit 2009 SP3 with LDAP Authentication, IIS level you need to enable only anonymous access and not basic authentication. In addition, I noticed when we enable IIS level authentication they did not trickle down to all the sub structure. Please double check this as well.

Documentation refenrence here : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/task_8DD08606EDAB48038E0A42D809F3DC58

From the documentation, Double-click the Authentication icon on the right and change the settings that appear as follows:

- Select the Anonymous Authentication row and click Enable in the
  Actions area on the right.
- Select each of the other rows in turn and
  for each row, click Disable in the Actions area on the right.

Also in case if you have the below handler mappings you need to remove them from web.config `[TRIDION_HOME]\web\WebUI\WebRoot`

```
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
```

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Hi Ram, thanks for the response. I have made the updates to the SiteEdit website authentication to enable only anonymous access. After restarting IIS, I was able to login, but instead of being routed to the staging website, I am routed to the Tridion CME.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the SiteEdit URL you're accessing? Is it "/" or default page? Try with the default page like `home.aspx` or `default.aspx` etc.